# I/FragmentNavigator: Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to have one navigation item for my game and have fragments on this navigation item change automatically with the switchFragment(). The other navigation item i made for stats but when i employ the switchfragment() the navigation bar doesnt respond and i get the error: Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private val gameViewModel: GameViewModel by viewModels()
private lateinit var navController: NavController

val gameFragment = GameFragment()
val guessWordFragment = GuessWordFragment()
val loseScreenFragment = LoseScreenFragment()
val winScreenFragment = WinScreenFragment()
val statsFragment = StatsFragment()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_activity_main) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

    findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNav)
        .setupWithNavController(navController)

    switchFragments()
    }


    fun switchFragments() {
        // switch between fragments when game PHASE changes with observer
        if(!statsFragment.isResumed) {
            gameViewModel.gamePhase().observe(this, Observer {
                when (it) {
                    GameViewModel.PHASE.SPIN ->                         
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .apply {
                            replace(R.id.fragment_activity_main, gameFragment)
                            commit()
                        }
                    GameViewModel.PHASE.WORD_GUESSING -> 
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .apply {
                            replace(R.id.fragment_activity_main, guessWordFragment)
                            commit()
                        }
                    GameViewModel.PHASE.Lose -> 
       supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .apply {
                            replace(R.id.fragment_activity_main, loseScreenFragment)
                            commit()
                        }
                    GameViewModel.PHASE.WIN -> 
       supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                        replace(R.id.fragment_activity_main, winScreenFragment)
                        commit()
                    }

                }
            })
        }
    }


   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || 
  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
     }

  }
```